# VSFTPD overall "super-user"

Tags: ftp

Is it possible to have a "super-user" which can login to VSFTPD and view ALL other home dirs?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the user is called `root`.

Comment: Thanks Grawity, but by default, root login over FTP only allows access to root's home folder.  Is there a way to let root login higher up the directory tree so it can access other FTP user's home folders?

Comment: @MFB: Do you have chroot enabled in vsftpd's config?

Comment: chroot_local_user=YES

Comment: @MFB: You will need to disable chroot for `root`. Since vsftpd doesn't seem to have an exclusion list, your choices are b) change root's home directory to `/` c) run a second copy of vsftpd, without chroot, but restricted to the `root` user.